# how to get robot's distance from an obstacle?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, i have a P3AT spawned in USARsim environment and i can navigate it through keyboard, i want to know its **distance from obstacles while it is in motion in the form of x and y coordinates**, but i don't know how to do it.

please help.

**I am using ROS-fuerte on UBUNTU 12.04 LTS**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198048/how-to-get-robot%27s-distance-from-an-obstacle??/) by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 351 on 2014-11-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Buy a depth sensor and put it on your robot, a Kinect or if you have money, a SICK laser for example. A cheaper solution would be using infrared sensors that have smaller range [infrared sensors](https://www.adafruit.com/products/164) . You can also use two normal cameras in a stereo setup.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2015-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on 2015-08-26**:
Thanks a lot @Mehdi, I have resolved it. as you suggested, sick laser worked for me. :)

**Comment by [SH_Developer](https://answers.ros.org/users/26427/sh_developer/) on 2017-07-28**:
Hi can you tel me how did you resolved. thank you !